# Dividing values based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have data frame like this one:

```
df<- data.frame(
  "Col1" = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P3",
              "P3"),
  "Col2" = c("L", "L&R", "R", "V", "V&N", "N", "M", "I", "I&M",
             "I&M&G"),
  "Value" = c("20", "5", "75", "30", "7", "63", "10", "80", "2","8"))
df
```

I want  to redefine the values in the third column based on the second column. I mean when I have L&R in the second column I want to divide its value by 2 (from the third column which equals to 5 in this case 5) and add this results to both L and R with in the same P1 group. So, L&R=5/2 will be 2.5. This 2.5 should be added to L in P1 group to be 22.5 and to R in P1 group to be 77.5. But in a case if I have two && in the column 2 ,I want the value to be divided by 3.  The final output should look like this:

```
df.output<- data.frame(
  "Col1" = c("P1",  "P1", "P2",  "P2", "P3", "P3","P3"),
  "Col2" = c("L",  "R", "V",  "N", "M", "I","G" ),
  "Value" = c("22.5",  "77.5", "33.5",  "66.5", "13.66",  "83.66","2.66"))
df.output
df.output
  Col1 Col2 Value
1   P1    L  22.5
2   P1    R  77.5
3   P2    V  33.5
4   P2    N  66.5
5   P3    M 13.66
6   P3    I 83.66
7   P3    G  2.66
```

I already had a code that worked when with one `&`  as below but I failed to make it  work when we have `&&`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(!str_count(Col2, "&") > 1) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(grepl("&", Col2), as.numeric(Value) / 2, as.numeric(Value))) %>%
  separate_rows(Col2, sep = "&") %>%
  group_by(Col1, Col2) %>%
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide `Value` by the number of `&` + 1.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Value = as.numeric(Value)/(str_count(Col2, "&") + 1)) %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(Col2, delim = "&") %>% 
  summarize(Value = sum(Value), .by = c(Col1, Col2))

  Col1 Col2     Value
1   P1    L 22.500000
2   P1    R 77.500000
3   P2    V 33.500000
4   P2    N 66.500000
5   P3    M 13.666667
6   P3    I 83.666667
7   P3    G  2.666667
```

Comment: Hi benson23, thank you so much this was magic! I really appreciate your help :). Could you please explain this part of the code for me please : `(str_count(Col2, "&") + 1))`.

Comment: @MarwahAl-kaabi `str_count(Col2, "&")` returns the number of the "&" symbol in `Col2`. If there's no "&" in `Col2`, this command returns zero, so zero + 1 means divide `Value` by 1, which is its own. Similarly, when there's one "&" in `Col2`, `str_count(Col2, "&")` returns 1, the extra `+ 1` ensures we divide it by 2. Similar for two or more "&". In short, you always want to divide `Value` by the number of "&" + 1 (sorry for my poor English, I don't know how to explain it better).

Comment: Hi benson23 Thank you so much I got it!!, you explained very well. God bless you.